# cannot set user data in session codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, session

please look at this.

The code below is from my model class (using datamapper orm)

```
 function login()
    {

        $u = new User();


        $u->where('username', $this->username)->get();


        $this->salt = $u->salt;

        $this->validate()->get();


        if (empty($this->id))
        {
            // Login failed, so set a custom error message
            $this->error_message('login', 'Username or password invalid');

            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            // Login succeeded
            $data = array
            (
                'username' => $u->username,
                'usergroup' => $u->usergroup->get(),
                'is_logged_in' => true

            );
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);


            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

when i do this i get

```
**Fatal error: Call to a member function set_userdata() on a non-object**
```

but when i do this instead

```
$data = array
            (
                'username' => $u->username,
                'usergroup' => $u->usergroup->get(),
                'is_logged_in' => true
            );
            $obj=& get_instance();
            $obj->session->set_userdata($data);
```

It works.

Please what is the right way to get this working ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you load the session library first? `$this->load->library('session')`

Comment: Uhm..and where are you using your first code?

Comment: Are you doing this from a library? In that case the `$this` will not contain the CI instance, see the section "Utilizing CodeIgniter Resources within Your Library" at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html

Comment: sorry for my late response. I am doing all of this from a model (datamapper orm model)

Answer (score 1):

your model did not extends CI_Model
after that you have to add constructor to your model
add this code to yours

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't provide enough information.
The first code looks fine, provided that:

1. You actually load the session class before calling it (you also need to create an encryption key in your configs).
   `$this->load->library('session');
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);`
2. The above code, or your code, is inside a controller, a model or a view.
   `$this` relates to the CI's superclass, in particular to an instance of the Session class, so if you're calling that inside a helper (collection of functions), or inside a library (where you need to create a CI instance first), it won't work.

Comment: @mojotaker I still don't see where you load the session class...is it autoloaded?